# Saving Peewee queries with multiple foreign key relationships against the same table

Tags: python, peewee

I have the following Peewee PostgreSQL model:

```
class Game(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db
        db_table = 'd_games'

    game_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    location = CharField()

    home_team = ForeignKeyField(Team, related_name='home_games')
    away_team = ForeignKeyField(Team, related_name='away_games')
```

You can see that the model has two foreign key relationships with a Team model.

I want to do something like:

```
games = Game.select(Game, Team).join(Team).limit(10)
for g in games:
    print '%s vs. %s' % (g.home_team.team_name, g.away_team.team_name)
```

Unfortunately, while the `home_team` relationship gets saved in the initial query:

```
# from the query log
'SELECT t1."game_id", t1."game_date", t1."location", t1."home_team_id", t1."away_team_id", t2."team_id", t2."team_name"
FROM "d_games" AS t1 
INNER JOIN "d_team" AS t2 
ON (t1."home_team_id" = t2."team_id") 
LIMIT 10
```

The `away_team` relationship does not, so a new query is getting executed every time I try to print out `g.away_team.team_name`.

How do I fix this so that both the `home_team` and `away_team` relationships get saved? I tried

```
games = Game.select(Game, Team, Team).join(Team).switch(Game).join(Team).limit(10)
```

But this gives me a `table name "t2" specified more than once` error, as the query that Peewee tries to execute is

```
'SELECT t1."game_id", t1."game_date", t1."location", t1."home_team_id", t1."away_team_id", t2."team_id", t2."team_name", t2."team_id", t2."team_name"
FROM "d_games" AS t1 
INNER JOIN "d_team" AS t2 
ON (t1."home_team_id" = t2."team_id") 
INNER JOIN "d_team" AS t2 
ON (t1."home_team_id" = t2."team_id") 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `Model.alias()` in these situations.  Here is an example:

```
HomeTeam = Team.alias()
AwayTeam = Team.alias()
query = (Game
         .select(Game, HomeTeam, AwayTeam)
         .join(HomeTeam, on=(Game.home_team == HomeTeam.id))
         .switch(Game)
         .join(AwayTeam, on=(Game.away_team == AwayTeam.id))
         .order_by(Game.id))
```

Which results in

```
SELECT 
    t1."id", t1."location", t1."home_team_id", t1."away_team_id", 
    t2."id", t2."name",
    t3."id", t3."name" 
FROM "d_games" AS t1 
INNER JOIN "team" AS t2 ON (t1."home_team_id" = t2."id") 
INNER JOIN "team" AS t3 ON (t1."away_team_id" = t3."id") 
ORDER BY t1."id
```

Then:

```
for game in query:
    print game.home_team.name, game.away_team.name
```